# Why does Ma'ii call Maggie by her full name?

Tags: rebecca-roanhorse, the-sixth-world

In Rebecca Roanhorse's *Trail of Lightning*, Ma'ii (aka Coyote) is the only person to call Maggie by her full name, Magdalena. This is stated explicitly:

> The same creature, looking mostly like a man and wearing the same outlandish Western costume, now sits drinking tea in my favorite chair in my living room.
>   "Magdalena, dear, is this really all you have? Tea?"
>   "Hello, Ma'ii," I greet him. He's the only person, or non-person as it were, who calls me by that name. But it would be useless to correct him.
>   <sub>*The Sixth World*, book 1: *Trail of Lightning*, chapter 12</sub>

Why does Ma'ii refer to her by "Magdalena"? How does this affect our reading of their interactions? Does this change the power dynamics?

**How does Ma'ii calling Maggie "Magdalena" affect the story?**